# How to get current date and time in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

**Summary**

I'm creating my first extension for VSCode in TypeScript, and want to create a new information message to display current date/time.

**What I've tried**

I've tried looking for some data/time keyword in the list of vscode key bindings. I've also tried looking for a function to get system date/time on Google only to come across solutions explaining data/time syntax and how to display a specific date/time but nothing to get the CURRENT data/time. I've also looked for it in vscode API documentation.

**Code part**

According to my understanding the code should be in `extension.ts` file in `activate` section where I register the command to implement `showInformationMessage` function call and send a string to it containing the date/time. So here is the code around the line where I store the current date/time:

```js
  let disposableShowTime = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    "extension.showTime",
    () => {
      // Display a message box to the user
      let dateTime = "22 March, 2019 12:45PM"; // store current data/time instead
      vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Current time: " + dateTime);
    }
  );
```

**Desired output**: `[Current Date/Time]`

**Actual output**: `22 March, 2019 12:45PM`

Answer (score 136, accepted):

To retrieve the current system Date/Time in javaScript/TypeScript you need to create a new `Date` object using parameterless constructor, like this:

```
let dateTime = new Date()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use angular and Moment type

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
...
//Change DATE_TIME_FORMAT by the format need
const DATE_TIME_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm'; 
let _now: Moment;
_now = moment(new Date(), DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
```

Comment: "We now generally consider Moment to be a legacy project in maintenance mode. It is not dead, but it is indeed done." This quote is directly from Project Status section of docs page on Momentjs website. https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: "Use a library" for something this simple is not constructive.

Answer (score -2):

### Maybe Luxon could be your friend

For Typescript I really like Luxon

```
npm install --save luxon
npm install --save-dev @types/luxon
```

and then

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
DateTime.now().toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_FULL);
```

See also https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/formatting.html

Comment: "Use a library" for something this simple is not constructive.